# how read info from a website "written in silverlight " using html 5

Tags: html, silverlight

I want to create an application using html5 that would be able to read info from a specific website .

Is such a thing possible, i check with many other websites, w3schools and such but to with no help.

Any headsup with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking "can I parse/crawl Silverlight website" ? No - you can however download the silverlight .xap file, unzip it and using ILSpy or other decompilation tool view the C# code used to create it. Your question isn't entirely clear so this is the only answer I can give.